# ERROR No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

I am trying to write a test for my controller but the test environment fails to load with the given stackTrace.

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('my.scope')")
    @GetMapping(value = "/path", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Set<String>>> getPath() {
        return myService.pathFunction()
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
```

and following is how I've configured my security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String PRINCIPAL = "sub";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        JwtAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter =
            new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        authenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(...);
        authenticationConverter.setPrincipalClaimName(PRINCIPAL);

        http.csrf().disable()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);
    }
}
```

**The controller is working as needed but my test fails with this error. I am not using any customer JwtDecoder**

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class)
class ControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = {"my.scope"})
    void controllerTest() throws Exception{
        Map<String, Set<String>> mapResponse = Map.of("key", Set.of("foo1", "foo2"));
        Mockito.when(myService.pathFunction()).thenReturn(Optional.of(mapResponse));

        MockHttpServletResponse result = mockMvc.perform(get("/configuration/api-registry")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse();

        String response = result.getContentAsString();
        assertTrue(response.contains("foo1"));
    }

}
```

How do I run this test ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' available
    at ...
```

Comment: does your application start when you run it without tests and does it respond when you call it.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Yes, the app runs. I've checked the network call. It is working as expected

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I added mocking the decoder in the test as

```
@MockBean
private JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;
```

and the test ran !

Answer (score 4):

Hi i was having same issue, then I realize on my test properties I missed to configure:

````
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: realm_uri_here
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resource-server.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs```
````

Answer (score 4):

This configuration test also resolved problem in Unit Tests.

```
oauth2:
  resourceserver:
    jwt:
      issuer-uri: test
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using `@SpringBootTest`. It started appearing when upgrading from spring boot version `2.5.12` to `2.7.8`.

I could fix it by changing

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
```

to

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```